# Big-O notation of two loops nested within loop

Tags: c++, big-o

I have the following code running to check for prime pairs up till a certain condition (p*q<=n) and I'm unsure if the Big-O notation for this would be O(n^2) or O(NlogN):

In main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
    int n, q;
    cin >> n;

    for (int p = 0; p * (p + 2) <= n; p++)
    {
        q = p+2;
        if (isPrime(p) && isPrime(q))
            // output (p,q)
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main for loop will scale as `sqrt(n)`.  While the prime function will scale linearly for its input, the input is always roughly `sqrt(n)`.  Hence your total run time will scale as `n^.5 * (n^.5 + n^.5) = 2n`.  So that's `O(N)`.

Comment: It's may also be worth mentioning that the complexity of `isPrime` can be improved to `O(√n)` by changing the loop condition to `i * i <= n` instead of `i <= n / 2`.